# Can't start Docker-Desktop when remoting into Ubuntu machine

Tags: 22.04, docker, remote-desktop, rdp

I run Ubuntu 22.04 on a machine that I remote into via RDP on my Windows machine. Remote connection is enabled on the Ubuntu machine via the built-in remote desktop sharing feature.

I have Docker-desktop installed on the Ubuntu machine and I can run docker desktop just fine when physically logging in and working on the Ubuntu machine. However, the second I remote into the Ubuntu machine I cannot start docker desktop. An error message pops up saying "Something Went wrong" and it asks to quit, retry, or to report the error. Nothing else.

Anyone who struggled with similar issue?

THanks